# How to get firebase firestore generated id

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i had an issue where i would like to generate the unique id without sending any data. Below is my code of getting the id, but i would like to get it before i could send the actual data to the database

```
var getUniqueId = firetoreDB.collection("collction").add({
  data: "data"
}).then(function (doc) {
  console.log(doc.id);
}).catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

The above code gets me the id but i wanted to get it without out sending a test data to the database

Comment: You can use [``firetoreDB.collection("collection").doc()``](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) to  to create a document with an auto-generated ID

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
firetoreDB.collection("collection").doc().id
```